# Is there a word that describes a person who easily gives up on others

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Example:

Person A had expectations of person B. After A gets to know B, person gives up on building a enriching relationship. A stops investing in the other person (i.e. stops giving feedback, stops trying to be understood or to understand). A presents a recurring pattern.

Comment: Maybe they ***got smart*** and ***wised up***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an adjective, I would say that person is being **apathetic**.

From encyclopedia.com

> showing or feeling no interest, enthusiasm, or concern.

Comment: Apathetic is the word

Comment: I respectfully disagree. An apathetic person would not have cared to begin with. @IberoMedia

Comment: @MadBanners Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's a difficult concept to fully explain in a word... but I'd say fickle or disloyal. I guess it depends, are you referring to the characteristics of A after giving up on B, or the entire situation (i.e. A starting off alright but then giving up on B)? @IberoMedia

Comment: @MadBanners I refer to the behavioral pattern of A. I think fickle is not the right word b/c it would mean A attitude would fluctuate between having expectations and apathy. I think disloyal does not apply; commitments or mutual agreements, implied or otherwise, are not part of the scenario

Comment: I'm confused here. You said that "A presents a recurring pattern", not that it was a one-off situation. Now, you talk about "a enriching relationship" within the scenario. Surely that's some kind of a commitment.

Comment: @MadBanners An apathetic person might not have previously been indifferent. Person A once cared and then became apathetic. The "recurring pattern" is evident when B reaches out to A and repeatedly receives no response.

Comment: Righto. Makes sense from that perspective. Does the word apathetic encompass 'easily giving up on others' per the title, though? @DevonYarbrough

Answer (score 1):

You could call Person A **fickle**.

From the Oxford Dictionary of English:

> changing frequently, especially as regards one's loyalties or affections.

Comment: Please provide some support for your answer. Answers should be definitive and well researched. I'm not the downvoter, btw.

Comment: @PhilSweet Apologies. The point was obvious to me, so I didn't think to elaborate on it. Clearly my original answer did not sink in, judging by the irrelevant answer that the asker chose.